# Spaceship show with a nanotechnology prison

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for a TV show involving a spaceship crew.  The one episode I know involves going into an abandoned ship and getting caught in a prison that involves nano bots.  The nano bots break you down painfully and rebuild you until you admit guilt for your crimes.  I know the crew was a darker skinned woman, a younger man, and his twin (at least).

I saw the episode a few months ago on Hulu+.  Since then, I have not been able to find it on Hulu or in my history so it may have been removed.  The show seems like  more recent show and it is American.

Comment: Do you remember when you watched the episode? Was it on broadcast TV, cable, or perhaps a website? Did it feel recent, or could it have been a rebroadcast?

Comment: It was on Hulu a couple months back.  It seems like it was a recent show but I'm unable to find it in my history or on the Hulu site.

Comment: Well, that helps some, but tomorrow. I should be asleep now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This sounds like the [A Glitch In The System](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4042182/) episode of Killjoys.

The main cast look like this: [image] - the two males play brothers.

The IMDB episode summary is a tad terse, but from what I remember, the crew come across a seemingly abandoned ship which the board, only to discover that it's slightly less abandoned than expected. It contains a secret nanotech project that inflicts pain upon the people it's applied to, the idea being that they will eventually break down and confess as the nano endlessly damages and heals them.

Comment: Looks like you found it!  Thanks for your help!